# Soap CustomBinding could not be found in .Net6

Tags: asp.net-core, soap, .net-6.0

I have old legacy `Standard2.1` project with Soap service with CustomBinding and i try to upgrade it to `.Net6`. on build I get following error

```
//Reference to type 'IBindingRuntimePreferences' claims it is defined in System.ServiceModel.Primitives', but it could not be found
```

I found `System.ServiceModel.Primitives 6.0.0` prerelease package for `.Net6`, but the error still remain the same. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Found the same. Have a .NET 6 project and using 4.10 versions of System.ServiceModel packages. Upgrading to 6.0.0 packages it can't find IBindingRuntimePreferences.

Comment: It looks like MS team will fix it soon https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/5202

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue on migrating a .Net Framework project to .Net 8.0 and could unblock this compiler error by explicitly casting the `BasicHttpBinding` object, which gets passed to the `CustomBinding` constructor, to the `Binding` class.

Code that throws the compiler error:

```cs
var httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
CustomBinding customBinding = new CustomBinding(httpBinding);
```

Code that worked:

```cs
var httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
CustomBinding customBinding = new CustomBinding((Binding)httpBinding); // explicit cast to Binding
```

Hope this helps until Microsoft fixes this issue.
Credit goes to this guy/comment:
https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/5202#issuecomment-1665137819